# Calculate previous week's start and end date

Tags: c#

What is the best way to calculate the previous week's start and end date in C#?  I.e. today 18 March would result in 9 March (Monday last week) and 15 March (Sunday last week).

I have seen this done with DayOfWeek and a switch statement to work out an offset but was wondering whether there is a more elegant way.

Comment: What about the complication of calculating the previous working week after close of business on Friday, which should then return the current week that Friday was in?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can skip the while loop and use

```
DateTime mondayOfLastWeek = date.AddDays( -(int)date.DayOfWeek - 6 );
```

This assumes you're using Monday as the first day of the week.

Comment: To answer the question, startOfWeek should be named sundayOfLastWeek.  "DateTime mondayOfLastWeek = date.AddDays(-(int)date.DayOfWeek - 6);"

Comment: Nice one liner approach.  I think the following would then work regardless of which day its run on:
mondayOfLastWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - 6 ); 
sundayOfLastWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);

Answer (score 35):

```
DayOfWeek weekStart = DayOfWeek.Monday; // or Sunday, or whenever
DateTime startingDate = DateTime.Today;

while(startingDate.DayOfWeek != weekStart)
    startingDate = startingDate.AddDays(-1);

DateTime previousWeekStart = startingDate.AddDays(-7);
DateTime previousWeekEnd = startingDate.AddDays(-1);
```

Read: Backtrack one day at a time until we're at the start of this week, and then subtract seven to get to the start of last week.

Answer (score 15):

using Fluent DateTime https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime

```
var dateTime = 1.Weeks().Ago();
var monday = dateTime.Previous(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
var sunday = dateTime.Next(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using DayOfWeek would be a way of achieving this:

```
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
    while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(-1);
    }

    DateTime startDate = date;
    DateTime endDate = date.AddDays(7);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a DateTime Extension method, that can be used with a DayOfWeek parameter:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime GetPreviousWeekDay(this DateTime currentDate, DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        int currentDay = (int)currentDate.DayOfWeek, gotoDay = (int)dow;
        return currentDate.AddDays(-7).AddDays(gotoDay-currentDay);
    }        
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2017, 01, 21);
        
Console.WriteLine(testDate.GetPreviousWeekDay(DayOfWeek.Sunday));
Console.WriteLine(testDate.GetPreviousWeekDay(DayOfWeek.Saturday));
```

---

To use it to get the previous week from the current date (as asked in the question):

```
var prevWkStartDate = DateTime.Now.GetPreviousWeekDay(DayOfWeek.Monday); 
var prevWkEndDate = DateTime.Now.GetPreviousWeekDay(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
Console.Write($"Previous week starts at {prevWkStartDate.ToShortDateString()}");
Console.WriteLine($" and ends at {prevWkEndDate.ToShortDateString()}");
```

Update: Seems that this requires a fix (example date: 10th December 2020):

```
public static DateTime GetPreviousWeekDay(this DateTime currentDate, DayOfWeek dow)
{
    int d = 0; if (dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday) { dow = DayOfWeek.Saturday; d = 1; }
    int currentDay = (int)currentDate.DayOfWeek, gotoDay = (int)dow;
    return currentDate.AddDays(-7).AddDays(gotoDay - currentDay + d);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Current accepted answer will fail for Sundays by giving the Monday of the current week instead of last weeks Monday.
(code with unit tests output)

```
DateTime mondayOfLastWeek = date.AddDays( -(int)date.DayOfWeek - 6 );
//Failed to get start of last-week from date-time: 2020-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z
//  Expected: 2020-02-17 00:00:00.000
//  But was:  2020-02-24 00:00:00.000
```

The following bit of code addresses this issue:

```
var dayOfWeek = (int) date.DayOfWeek - 1;
if (dayOfWeek < 0) dayOfWeek = 6;

var thisWeeksMonday = date.AddDays(-dayOfWeek).Date;
var lasWeeksMonday = thisWeeksMonday.AddDays(-7);
```

which can be reduced to a one-liner should you so desire (I do not recommend using this barely readable code...):

```
var mondayOfLastWeek  = date.AddDays(-(7 + ((int)date.DayOfWeek - 1 == -1 ? 6 : (int)date.DayOfWeek - 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is actually not correct.

You have to switch when the week "breaks", i.e. when it considers the week to end or start, and the formula in the accepted solution does not.

This is not so visible on a Monday as week start, but more so if you would consider Thursday the end of the week.

Correct formula is (for a Thursday as ending day):

```
DateTime thu = date.AddDays(-(int)(date.AddDays(-5).DayOfWeek) -1);
```

For Monday, the -5 would switch to -2.

Example code to print out

```
        String s = "";
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
            DateTime thu = date.AddDays(-(int)(date.AddDays(-5).DayOfWeek) -1);
            DateTime mon = date.AddDays(-(int)(date.AddDays(-2).DayOfWeek) -1);
            s += date.ToString() + " - Thu: " + thu.ToString() + " - Mon: " + mon.ToString() + "\r\n";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```