# c# previous week start date

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate previous week's start and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658353/calculate-previous-weeks-start-and-end-date)

I need to get the previous week start date in c#
for eg. today is Jan 9th.
previous week start date is Jan 1th.

I am using the following code

```
    DayOfWeek weekStart = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    DateTime startingDate = DateTime.Today;

    while (startingDate.DayOfWeek != weekStart)
        startingDate = startingDate.AddDays(-1);

    DateTime previousWeekStart = startingDate.AddDays(-7);
```

Is this the best way in c#

Thanks

Comment: Assuming start of the week is Sunday?

Answer (score 14):

As previously stated the duplicate's response will probably do for you

```
mondayOfLastWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - 6 );
sundayOfLastWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
```

Comment: He doesn't want Today-7, he wants StartOfCurrentWeek-7

Comment: This doesn't actually give the answer as the last week may not have started 7 days ago (as per OP's example).

Comment: OP says `I need to get the previous week start date in c#  for eg. today is Jan 9th` ... So, I can just calculate what was the date 7 days earlier from today. I don't see any wrong in there. Let me know if my understanding is wrong

Comment: Hi Rahul - he isn't asking what the date was one week ago, as per your answer. He is asking what date the previous week started on. e.g. in Gregorian last sunday - 7 days