# How to get a previous week number based on current date in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get the number of previous week of previous year in c#. For example, today is week 1 of 2015 and I want to get the last week as in week number 52 of year 2014.

Currently my code is,

```
var weekNo = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
             DateTime.Now.Date,
             currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
             currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

And it returns week 1. I have a loop which used to run from week number **1** to **weekNo - 1** to get the data of last year but now **weekNo - 1** returns 0 and I want it to return 52.

So, it should be something like this,

```
int lastweekNo = lastWeek(datetime.today);  //returns 52 for today's date, 1 for next Monday's date,..
```

Let me know how can I achieve this. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Btw. you should really unit test your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this gives you the current week number:

```
currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
    DateTime.Now.Date,
    currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
    currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Wouldn't this give you the previous week number?

```
currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date,
    currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
    currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to put +1 David.

Answer (score 1):

To get the week number of the previous week, just get the week number of the day seven days ago:

```
var weekNo = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
         DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7),
         currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
         currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the number of previous week of previous year

It's not clear what's a “previous week of previous year”.

> today is week 1 of 2015 and I want to get the last week as in week number 52 of year 2014

To get the number of the last week in the previous year:

```
GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 31), … )
```

> And it returns week 1. I have a loop which used to run from week number 1 to weekNo - 1 to get the data of last year but now weekNo - 1 returns 0 and I want it to return 52.

So in case your loop is from `1` to `week - 1`, then in case `week` has the value `1`, it's correct that it doesn't execute at all. You just can't take `DateTime.Now` and, without any further constraints, assume the week number will correspond with the year you are trying to work with.

Comment: The OP was looking to get the week number from last week of a given date, not the last week in the previous year..

Comment: Note that OP wanted not only "52 for today's date", but also "1 for next Monday's date". He always wants previous week number, but it should handle dates from first week of year.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney “I want to get the last week as in week number 52 of year 2014.” — it *seems* based on today (Jan 2nd 2015) he wants to know the last week number in the previous year (2014). The rest of the question isn't clear.

Comment: @OndrejTucny See code comments on the bottom most code snippet in OP.

Comment: @Tormod Next Monday, meeting Jan 5th 2015, will be week **no. 2**.

Comment: @OndrejTucny ... which then would not make "last week" week no. 1?

Comment: @Tormod Last (previous, to avoid confusion) week number relative to Jan 5, 2015 can be 1 or 52, depending on the year you'd consider. The OP should be thinking of The year *at the first place*, and then think of any week numbers providing their intent ultimately is to loop through weeks #1 to #previous-relative-to-today.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Monday as the first day of the week.

```
 DateTime sundayOfLastWeek = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.Date.DayOfWeek);

 MessageBox.Show(GetIso8601WeekOfYear(sundayOfLastWeek).ToString());
```

GetIso8601WeekOfYear

```
public static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
        {

            DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
            if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
            {
                time = time.AddDays(3);
            }

            // Return the week of our adjusted day
            return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        }
```

[The above code is taken from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658353/calculate-previous-weeks-start-and-end-date)